# How do I delete route to "link#8" gateway on MacOS?

Tags: networking, vpn, mac-osx, mac, route

How do I delete default route of "link#8" gateway on MacOS El Capitan? It's a route automaticaly added after connecting to IPSec VPN.

```
$ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            link#8             UCS            21        0   utun0
default            192.168.1.1        UGScI          16        0     en1
10.2.2.71          10.2.2.71          UH              0       11   utun0
10.19.5.40         link#8             UHWIi           1       27   utun0

$ ifconfig 
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 60:33:4b:04:d4:7a 
    inet 192.168.1.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
    inet 10.2.2.71 --> 10.2.2.71 netmask 0xffffff00 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
```

This doesn't work

```
$ sudo route -n delete default -ifscope utun0
route: writing to routing socket: not in table
delete net default: not in table

$ sudo route -n delete default "link#8"
route: bad address: link#8
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked:

```
sudo route -n delete default -link 8
```

Comment: `sudo route delete -ifscope utun0 default`. Thanks for the `-link` tip, I hadn't picked up on that from the man page.